# Get bitrate from shoutcast

Tags: c#, audio, http-live-streaming, shoutcast

To get the bitrate from a shoutcast people used to take it from the Metadata header like this example:

```
icy-notice1: This stream requires 
<A href="http://www.winamp.com/" target=_blank>Winamp</A> 

icy-notice2: SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.5

icy-name: RadioABF.net - Paris Electro Spirit Live From FRANCE

icy-genre: Techno House Electronic

icy-url: <A href="http://www.radioabf.net/" target=blank>http://www.radioabf.net/</A>

content-type: audio/mpeg
icy-pub: 1

icy-metaint: 32768


icy-br: 160
```

but some shoutcast dont give this information

My question is how to get the bitrate from a shoutcast ?

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to get the bitrate is to decode the audio stream.

While SHOUTcast servers give this hint in their headers, it isn't guaranteed to be accurate, as the bitrate can change.  Other servers sending streams over HTTP don't always follow the header pattern that SHOUTcast does, as you have seen.

You cannot simply measure the speed in which you receive data either, as many servers send large buffers initially to fill the client buffer and test connection speed.

If you cannot decode the stream, many codecs will be putting that bitrate in their frame header.  For MPEG, [the first four bits of the third byte in the frame header give you the bitrate](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html).

Comment: This is further complicated by variable bitrate streams. A spot check won't inform you of the average or maximum bitrates, which are probably the most interesting ones to know.

Answer (score 0):

Shoutcast V1 has a special page with bitrate (and other) information.
Lets say your shoutcast is running on 
http://some-streaming-server:8000
then this page url will be:
http://some-streaming-server:8000/7.html

The body of that page looks somthing like this:

```
 <HTML><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"></head<body>4,1,36,80,4,64,Artist - title</body></html>
```

Split that text by commas and you will get:

- Current listeners
- Stream status
- Peak listeners
- Maximum number of listeners (from server start)
- Unique listeners
- **Bitrate**
- Song title